# Axiom reuse with Typeclasses in Coq

Tags: coq

I am trying to use typeclasses for code reuse, but I am getting setoid errors applying parent typeclass axioms in child typeclass theorems. I made a MRE with the following Equality and Addition operations:

```
Require Import Setoid.

(* Equality *)
Parameter CEq : forall A, A->A->Prop.
Arguments CEq [A] _ _.
Notation "x ¦ y" := (CEq x y) (at level 70, no associativity).
Axiom ceq_reflexivity: forall A, forall a:A, a¦a.
Axiom ceq_symmetry: forall A, forall a b:A, a¦b->b¦a.
Axiom ceq_transitivity: forall A, forall a b c:A, a¦b->b¦c->a¦c.
Add Parametric Relation A : (A) (@CEq A)
  reflexivity proved by (@ceq_reflexivity A)
  symmetry proved by (@ceq_symmetry A)
  transitivity proved by (@ceq_transitivity A)
  as ceq_rel.

(* Addition *)
Parameter CAdd: forall A, A->A->A.
Arguments CAdd [A] _ _.
Infix "±" := CAdd  (at level 50, left associativity).
```

The following are the parent and child classes:

```
(* Parent Typeclass *)
Class CDiscT (CDisc: Set) := {
  O: forall CDisc, CDisc;
  cdisc_add_neutral:forall CDisc, forall x:CDisc, x±(O CDisc)¦x;
}.

(* Natural Set & Child Typeclass *)
Parameter CNat: Set.
Class CNatT `{CDiscT CNat} := {}.
```

And here is the failing theorem:

```
(* Axiom inheritance test *)
Example test `{CNatT}: (O CNat)¦(O CNat)±(O CNat).
Proof.
  rewrite <- cdisc_add_neutral. (* Error *)
  reflexivity.
Qed.
```

Here is the error:

```
Error:
Tactic failure: setoid rewrite failed: Unable to satisfy the following constraints:
In environment:
H : CDiscT CNat
H0 : CNatT

?s : "subrelation (CEq (A:=Prop)) (Basics.flip Basics.impl)"
```

What is missing here to be able to use CDiscT axioms inside CNatT theorems? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be in part because your example is too simplified, but rewriting right-to-left with `cdisc_add_neutral` is problematic because the right-hand side `x` matches anything and can have any type.

The error you get is that Coq is trying to rewrite the whole goal with it, but that would use logical implication `impl`, which in turn requires that your relation `CEq` is a subrelation of `impl`.

You can avoid this by specializing the lemma a bit:

```
  rewrite <- (cdisc_add_neutral CNat) at 1.
```

You need the `at 1` because now the subterm that matches is `O CNat`, but it occurs three times in your goal. `rewrite` tries to rewrite all of them by default, which requires `Proper` instances that are missing here. (You can get those via the `Parametric Morphism` mechanism described in the manual).

Also, you can rewrite left-to-right:

```
rewrite cdisc_add_neutral
```